# Howto: thread split a subnet into sublists and spawn a thread for each list

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have created a network scanner, that looks for a specific port on a range of IP's. I would like to thread the application but I am getting and error message

```
ERROR:
for worker in range(network.hosts):
TypeError: 'method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Now I understand why the error is there it is because the IP Address is not an INT.  However,  what I would prefer to do is split the subnet into equal parts and run X number of IP's on a per thread bases.

Example

```
Thread 1 192.168.1 - 30
Thread 2 192.168.31 - 60
Thread 3 192.168.61 - 90
Thread 4 192.168.91 - 120
Thread 5 192.168.121 - 150
Thread 6 192.168.151 - 180
Thread 7 192.168.181 - 210
Thread 8 192.168.211 - 240
Thread 9 192.168.241 - 254
```

Something along these lines. I"m not quite sure how to do this.  I am posting the main function, the tcp ping 
 and the threading function.

I suspect I need to get a list of IP's and then somehow tell the thread to execute on X number of IP's at a time but not really sure how to do that.

Thanks for the help in advance

It appears as though you can't start a worker on a list?  Here is where I am currently in regards to the error message.  The other threads seem to have the same error message. this is jsut the last lines of the output.

```
Exception in thread Thread-27:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: threader() argument after * must be an iterable, not type



  File "pyportscanner", line 366, in 
    main()
  File "pyportscanner", line 154, in main
    for worker in range(iperf[0:]):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Code:

```
 # Library Imports
from datetime import datetime
from queue import Queue
import threading
import argparse
import logging
import os
import socket
import ipaddress


# Defines Global Variables
BUFFER = 4096  # 4k The size of the TCP Buffer
MESSAGE = 'TA:getattrlong'.encode('utf-8')
TCP_PORT = 2359  # Sets Port to 2359 (iPerf Remote)
MIN_SCAN_TIMEOUT = .010  # Sets Min socket timeout to 10ms 'milliseconds'
MAX_SCAN_TIMEOUT = .160  # Sets Max socket timeout to 100ms 'milliseconds'
IPERF_QUERY_TIMEOUT = 5  # Sets socket timeout to 5s 'seconds'

# File I/O Vars
LOG_FILE = 'iperfdiscovery.log'  # Testing log, revert to above on actual AirCheck G2
IPERF_ACCESSORY_FILE = 'iperfaccessory'  # iPerf Accessory output file
OPTION_FILE = '/mnt/mmc3/iperfaccessory.conf'  # iPerf Accessory option file "Allows increasing timeout"

THREADS = 50


def main():
    """
    iPerf Accessory Discovery Utility for AirCheck G2 V2.0

    :return:
    """
    # Logging (File Location, Log level, date, message)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE, filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

    # Removes iPerf Accessory File if its exists File Output Logs errors
    # NOTE: File cannot be found is normal in the log expected behavior
    try:
        os.remove(IPERF_ACCESSORY_FILE)
    except OSError as err_msg:
        logging.debug('DEBUG: OS Error %s', err_msg)
        pass

    # Arg Parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('network', help='The IP/Network you wish to scan', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timeout', nargs='?', const=1, type=float, help='Optional socket timeout')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.9')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--options', action='store_true',
                        help='Uses the advanced configuration options if present')
    parser.add_argument('-th', '--threading', action='store_true',
                        help="Enables multiple threads")

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
        network = args.network  # Gets network from args parse mandatory argument
        network = (ipaddress.ip_network(network, strict=False))

        if args.options:
            OPTION_FILE()

        if args.timeout:
            MIN_SCAN_TIMEOUT = args.timeout
            print(MIN_SCAN_TIMEOUT)
        if args.threading:
            q = Queue
            iperf = []
            subnet = []

            for host in network.hosts():  # List of IP's in subnet
                subnet.append(str(host))

            for i in range(0, len(subnet), THREADS):
                iperf.append(subnet[i: i + THREADS])

            for x in range(THREADS):
                t = threading.Thread(target=threader, args=q)
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()

            for worker in range(iperf[0:]):
                q.put(worker)

            q.join()

        else:
            tcp_port_ping(network)

    except KeyboardInterrupt as err_msg:
        logging.debug(err_msg)

    except OSError as err_msg:
        logging.debug(err_msg)


def threader(q):
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        t_tcp_port_ping(worker)
        q.task_done()


def t_tcp_port_ping():

    active_ip_count = 0
    tmp_iperf_list = []

    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as tcp_sock:
            result = tcp_sock.connect_ex((str(host), TCP_PORT))  # Check if IP is Valid and Port is Open
            if result == 0:
                active_ip_count += 1  # Increment valid IP counter
                tmp_iperf_list.append(host)  # Appends iPerf attributes to iPerf Remote list
                logging.debug("DEBUG: IP(s) to be scanned %s", host)  # Debug IP Address of remote(s)

    except OSError as err_msg:
        logging.debug('Socket Error %s', err_msg)
        print(err_msg)
        pass

    print(tmp_iperf_list)
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could pear this down to the smallest manageable chunk that will reproduce your problem.

Comment: as I understand it, iperf is a list of lists of hosts (as strings), where each sublist is a block of work for a single thread? also, you pass `worker` to `t_tcp_port_ping` within `threader`, but as defined, it receives no args...

Comment: also, I can probably think of about 10 places you could use locks to make this more stable

Comment: Aaron,  The iperf list is a list of lists with 50 IP's per list.  I was hoping to have the scanner then run a thread for each sublist.  Or is this even a good way about going about it.  Is there a way to thread the main list so it runs against X number of IP's? and in terms of locks honestly not sure what you mean.  The whole idea of threading is new to me. I'm at a complete loss on how to implement this.   The goal is this.  Take a subnet say a /20 and break it up into smaller chunks each running in its own thread checking to see if port 2359 is open.

Comment: locks are a type of mutex to synchronize between threads so multiple threads don't read / write to a resource out of order. This problem in general seems to me like a good fit for a [thread pool](http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/python-thread-pool.html) however. that would make it easy to launch however many worker threads you want, and remove some of the complexity of chunking the work out to each thread

Comment: So you think a pool would be better.  And rather I want 50 or not I don't know.  Let's start small 4 let's see how it goes.  I'm sure any amount of threading is bound to gain some speed.